# Finding a real stud

Tags: studs

I have a stud finder that "sees" through drywall. However, how does one know what is being reported is a stud and not say a pipe running through the wall? I use standard size spacing of 16" and electrical outlets to make certain it is a true stud. Are there other ways to make certain before drilling?

Comment: Or this? [How do I ensure that I hit studs and not pipes?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101523/how-do-i-ensure-that-i-hit-studs-and-not-pipes)

Comment: More ideas: [What's the least intrusive way to find out what's in a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/whats-the-least-intrusive-way-to-find-out-whats-in-a-wall)

Comment: Even more: [How can I hit studs and avoid cables when installing a TV mount?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214362/how-can-i-hit-studs-and-avoid-cables-when-installing-a-tv-mount)

Comment: [The treasure trove](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+using+studfinder&rlz=1)

Answer (score 3):

I have some version of electronic studfinder.

When I want to know where a stud *really* is, I use a strong magnet to look for screws (or nails in old drywall) holding the drywall to the stud. Find several and draw a line to avoid being thrown off by one poorly placed screw.

Pipes should not have screws into them ;^)

Answer (score 2):

My 99% confidence approach is to simply *find more studs*. If you see the pattern, including any around doors and windows, you can be reasonably sure you have lumber and not pipes.

Once you do, cross-reference with baseboard nails, etc., and then *drill slowly*. You can tell a lot by feel once you get through the drywall.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.mycarpentry.com/framing-a-wall.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Pipes should not be in contact with the drywall/lath, and thus should not affect the vibration that electronic stylus finders rely upon. Ditto wires.

The other answers, and comments, give other answers/approaches/safety nets.

Or you can spend more and get an electronic stud-finder that uses multiple approaches so it *can* report pipes and wires.